# How to implement Multiple notifications onclick in android using fcm?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase cloud messaging to receive notifications in android. Each notification should be navigated to different Activity. I am receiving multiple notifications, but when I click on any one of multiple notifications it is navigating to correct activity, but remaining notifications redirecting to default page

Here is my code

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    String flag = "0";
    String cid = "0",status11,opdat;

    int ff;
    String docid = "0";
    Date d = new Date();
//deyaPAy
String docId;
    String FirstName = "0";
    String Amount = "0";
    String Flag = "0";
    String status = "0";
    String SenderID1 = "0" ;
    String ReceiverId1 = "0" ;
    String ReceiverPhoneNumberst ="0";
    String SenderAutoId ="0";
    String SenderPhonenumber = "0";
    String sendername = "0";
    String receiverautoID ="0";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        //user_id = mAuth.getUid();
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        //
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: 
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            String id = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            Log.e("id",id);
            flag = remoteMessage.getData().get("code");
            Log.e("qwert",flag);


            cid = remoteMessage.getData().get("OrderId");


            //deyaPay
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            Amount = remoteMessage.getData().get("Amount");
            System.out.println(Amount);
            SenderID1=remoteMessage.getData().get("SenderID");
            System.out.println("Senderid"+SenderID1);
            ReceiverId1=remoteMessage.getData().get("ReceiverId");
            ReceiverPhoneNumberst=remoteMessage.getData().get("ReceiverPhoneNumber");
            SenderPhonenumber = remoteMessage.getData().get("SenderPhoneNumber");
            //long ReceiverPhoneNumber = Long.parseLong(ReceiverPhoneNumberst);
            SenderAutoId=remoteMessage.getData().get("SenderAutoId");
            status = remoteMessage.getData().get("Status");
            sendername = remoteMessage.getData().get("SenderName");
            receiverautoID = remoteMessage.getData().get("ReceiverAutoID");
            System.out.println(Flag);
            Log.d(TAG, "From:" + remoteMessage.getFrom());
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification MessageBody:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification data:" + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        if(Objects.equals(flag, "01") || Objects.equals(flag, "03") || Objects.equals(flag, "04") || Objects.equals(flag, "05")) {

            final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("Title", remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            map.put("Body", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            map.put("DateTime",d);

            DocumentReference dr = db.collection("UserProfile").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("Notifications").document();
            docid = dr.getId();
            dr.set(map);
        }

        else{

            Log.e("","");
        }
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),flag,cid,docid, sendername, Amount, SenderAutoId, status,SenderPhonenumber);


        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody,String flag1,String cid1,String docid1, String FirstName, final String amount, String senderautoid, String finalStatus,String SenderPhonenumber) {

        System.out.println("messagebody"+messageBody);
        System.out.println("Amount"+amount);
        System.out.println("name"+FirstName);
        System.out.println("senderid"+senderautoid);
        String f1 = flag1;
        Intent intent = null;

        Date d = new Date();
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(d);
        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault()).format(d);

        // write data to database base on falg values and method of delivery


        if(Objects.equals(flag, "05")){
            final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("Id",cid1);
            map.put("Type","Returned");
            map.put("Date",date);
            map.put("Time",time);
            db.collection("UserProfile").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("Notifications").document(docid1).set(map, SetOptions.merge());
            intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, ReturnsClosedDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("ReturnId",cid);

        } 
        else if(Objects.equals(flag, "11")){
                intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, openorderdetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("Orderid",cid);
        }
        else if(Objects.equals(flag, "12")){
                intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, openorderdetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("Orderid",cid);
        }
        else if(Objects.equals(flag, "13")){

                intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, openorderdetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("Orderid",cid);
        }
        else if(Objects.equals(flag, "07")){

            intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, ReturnsOpenDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("ReturnId",cid);
        }
        else if(Objects.equals(flag, "14")){

            intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, ReturnsOpenDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("ReturnId",cid);
        }
        else {
                intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, ProfileNavigation.class);
        }



        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        // Notification icons

        String channelId = "fcm_default_channel";
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifyicon)
                        .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        }

        //notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to replace `PendingIntent` requestCode 0 with `new Random().nextInt()` as below

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, new Random().nextInt(), intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: is that new Random().nextInt() or new Random.nextInt()

Comment: `new Random().nextInt()`